# conditionally run tasks when given multiple input to a variable

Tags: ansible

I have written a ansible script which runs fine when there is only 1 input to a variable:

```
---
- hosts: ListA
  vars:
    app-dir: /tmp
    service_name: exampleAAA
    roles:
    - prechecks
```

Below is the task i am using and working when only one service defined for service_name:
    ---

```
- name: check service status
  command: "{{app_dir}}/app-name {{item}} status"
  with_items: '{{service_name}}'
  ignore_errors: yes
  register: service_status

- name: starting service if it's in failed state
  set_fact: serviceTostart={{item}}
  with_items: '{{service_name}}'
  when: service_status | failed

- shell: "{{app_dir}}/app-name {{serviceTostart}} start"
  when: service_status | failed
```

As per my usecase i need this to work for below:

```
vars:
  service_name:
  - exampleAAA
  - exampleBBB
  - exampleCCC
```

When i run the playbook after defining multiple service_name. it shows **failed** status of service in step **check service status** but it says ok in rest of the steps. When i check the status of services there is no change. How can i make it work for multiple service_names ???

So here i what the script should do(I am stuck with points 2 & 3, can someone please let me know what need to be done to make it work):

1. The script will check the status of all the services mentioned (it is doing this correctly)
2. If one of the service status shows as stop. It will go the tasks which will run the command to bring back that particular service.
3. If after one start the service still does not come up then script should fail ( I am yet to write code for this part).

Comment: I don't see any "check service name" task, did you mean "check service status"?

Comment: sorry, it was "check service status" @techraf . I've added addtional info to the question description

Comment: I don't know how to proceed for points 2 & 3 mentioned in what the script should do

Comment: Do you really need to check the status in the first place? Can't you just start the services? If the service is already running, nothing should happen.

Comment: Yeah... as per the process we follow, it is mandatory to first check the status of service and only if the service is not up I need to start it. In case service does not comes up after first try then we need to fail the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly the answer to your question is in the documentation: [Using `register` with a loop](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#using-register-with-a-loop).

```
- name: check service status
  command: "{{app_dir}}/app-name {{item}} status"
  with_items: "{{service_name}}"
  ignore_errors: yes
  register: service_status

- shell: "{{app_dir}}/app-name {{item.item}} start"
  when: item | failed
  with_items: "{{service_status.results}}"
```

Comment: First task will be red, but not failed in terms of playbook workflow. We can use `| failed` to test individual item, because it relies on `rc` codes and other stuff of result object. If something fails during start attempt, the task will be marked as failed for real and ansible will stop further execution.

Comment: I think it's a kind of `service nginx status` / `service nginx start` but with some proprietary wrappers or smth.

Comment: Thanks again Konstantin for your help, @techraf the "app-name" is a script which start, stop & check status of the services of our application.

Comment: I've one last querry for this, if after 1 try  the application does not comes up then I need to fail the task. How i can integrate this part ? for now I've added the "check service status" task again without "ignore errors" in the end of task, it does the job but code is redundant

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov Cool. I've learnt a new thing: that people can emphasise a correct condition (coincidentally called "failure") and at the same time leave the real problem in a regular font.