# Looped checks in Ansible

Tags: loops, automation, ansible, conditional-statements

For example, I have a list like this:

```
vms:
  - name: "vm1"
    desc: "first"
    network:
      ip: "10.0.0.10"
      prefix: "16"
  - name: "vm2"
    desc: "second"
    network:
      ip: "10.0.0.11"
      prefix: "16"
```

I want to create VMs with OpenNebula in a loop with checking if there is already created VM. I've made a check task:

```
- name: Check if VM "{{ item.name }}" already created
  become_user: oneadmin
  ignore_errors: yes
  shell: onevm list --csv | grep "{{ item.name }}"
  register: created_vms
  with_items:
    - "{{ vms }}"
```

but I don't know how to make "Create VM" task correctly with loop + 'when' statement.

Comment: Here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44129741/2795592

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Konstantin Suvorov for his comment!
Here is an answer for my case:

```
- name: Check if VMs already created
  become_user: oneadmin
  ignore_errors: yes
  shell: onevm list --csv | grep "{{ item.name }}"
  register: created_vms
  with_items: "{{ vms }}"

- name: Create VMs
  become_user: oneadmin
  command: onevm create --name "{{ item.1.name }}"
  when: item.0|failed
  with_together:
    - "{{ created_vms.results }}"
    - "{{ vms }}"
```